# Compare two Columns and delete the gap Using Macro

Tags: excel, macros, excel-2013, vba

I have an Excel file and i want to compare the date in columns A and D and delete the gap between them.
For example based on this picture 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKMHD.png)
Time in column A start at 14:56:23 and in D at 14:56:18. So i want to delete all the data in column D till 14:56:23 so that it will be the same in both A and D.
this problem will be repeated many times so i want to develop a macro to do it.

that is a small program to compare just first two cells in column A and D

```
Sub Edit_Date_time()

Dim r As Range
Dim l As Range

Set r = Range("A2")
Set l = Range("D2")

    If r.Value <> l.Value Then
        Range("D2:E2").Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If


   End Sub
```

the problem is that the cells contain date & time so i can not compare it as values.I have also to expand this code to cover the whole A2 & D2 column not only the first two cells.

Comment: Instead of importing the files into the same worksheet, you should import them into separate worksheets - then merge them with the processing you require (T-P order, eliminate headers, deal with missing timestamps, etc.)

Comment: If you have more data in a file than can be loaded into a worksheet, you will need to read / store using a loop. Look into using the [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711216(v=vs.71).aspx). There are [examples on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233203/how-do-i-use-filesystemobject-in-vba)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i will try it.

Comment: I solved most of the problems, now i am trying to compare the cells in every row and delete the lower value until they are equal then move to next row,compare.......    can you help me with a macro to do it

Comment: Have you [searched the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806551/delete-a-row-if-the-date-does-not-match)?

Comment: no but could you tell me how generalize this line                                      Set rBig = Range("A4:A20459")                                                                       to work through the entire file?

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) the best way to find the last used row is `LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`.  You specify the range in column A as `rBig=Range("A4:A"&LastRow)`. If you need to go through multiple worksheets, you will need to do this inside a loop.

Comment: I have followed the updates to this question for almost a day now and it is still unclear to me whether you want to retain only the records that have *datetime, temp1, temp2* and *pressure* or whether you also want to retain records for possible *datetime, temp1, temp2, <blank>* or *datetime, <blank>, blank>, pressure* as well.

Comment: i have just edited the question.

Comment: @OldUgly  the code in the site , you have mentioned , is not working. i tried to edit it but it is still not working.

Comment: Still unclear. You did not address the three different scenarios that I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: @Jeeped i want the first scenario datetime, temp1, temp2 and pressure

Comment: @Mohamed - now would be a good time to share with us what code you have tried, what errors it is causing, and we can provide some specific help.

Comment: @OldUgly i attached the code. it may seem very simple but i have just started learning VB.

Comment: Why can't you compare one date/time to another date/time? They should both resolve as (for all intents and purposes) doubles. You can also force the comparison explicitly as doubles by using the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) instead of the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx). Are they coming in as text?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has morphed many times, but I am going with the question "how to eliminate rows without matching timestamps" ...

Comparing timestamps can be tricky, even if they are correctly formatted. You would expect `2/17/2016 14:56:29` to be equal to `2/17/2016 14:56:29`, but there may be a difference in milliseconds that you cannot see in the string or in the general format. Therefore, you should use a tolerance when determining <, >, or =.

Remember, with timestamps 1.0 = 1 day. So 1/10 of a second is (1/24/60/60/10).

I assume you want to delete pressure rows when those timestamps are earlier than the corresponding temperature timestamps, AND you want to delete temperature rows when those timestamps are earlier than the corresponding pressure timestamps.

This means, worst case, a loop will need to go through the entire data set twice.

I tested code against this data ...

[image]

After processing, the yellow cells should align, the orange rows should be deleted. Here are the results I get ...

[image]

using this code ...

```
Sub ParseDateTime()
Dim TRange As Range, PRange As Range
Dim iLoop As Long, LoopEnd As Long
Dim theRow As Long, LastRow As Long

' set the range for the temperature data
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set TRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C" & LastRow)
LoopEnd = LastRow

' set the range for the pressure data
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set PRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:E" & LastRow)
If LastRow > LoopEnd Then LoopEnd = LastRow

' loop through the range
theRow = 1
For iLoop = 2 To 2 * LoopEnd
    theRow = theRow + 1
' stop searching when no more data
    If TRange(theRow, 1) = "" And PRange(theRow, 1) = "" Then Exit For
' if out of temperature data, eliminate the rest of the pressure data
    If TRange(theRow, 1) = "" Then
        PRange.Rows(theRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        theRow = theRow - 1
    End If
' if out of pressure data, eliminate the rest of the temperature data
    If PRange(theRow, 1) = "" Then
        TRange.Rows(theRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        theRow = theRow - 1
    End If
' eliminate pressure rows where the time stamp is earlier than the temperature timestamp
    If (TRange(theRow, 1).Value > PRange(theRow, 1).Value) And _
       (Abs(TRange(theRow, 1).Value - PRange(theRow, 1).Value) >= (1# / 24# / 60# / 60# / 10#)) Then
        PRange.Rows(theRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        theRow = theRow - 1
    Else
' eliminate temperature rows where the time stamp is earlier than the pressure timestamp
        If (TRange(theRow, 1).Value < PRange(theRow, 1).Value) And _
           (Abs(TRange(theRow, 1).Value - PRange(theRow, 1).Value) >= (1# / 24# / 60# / 60# / 10#)) Then
            TRange.Rows(theRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            theRow = theRow - 1
        End If
    End If
Next iLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: This very helpful. Thank you very much. I edited the question many times as i solved some of these problems.

Comment: if you do not mind, i have another small problem. This problem with large data as it will not be possible to store it in one sheet. how can i add a line to open another sheet when the data are too large?

Comment: Post as a new question

Answer (score 0):

The redefinition(s) of this question makes it hard to deal with; particularly so as some (now removed) criteria would render some solutions to the current problem impractical.

I remember when your data came from multiple CSV files; some containing temperatures and some containing pressures. In fact there was so much data that it could conceivably 'spill' over to another worksheet. This fact alone renders individual worksheet value comparisons impractical. Even if it all fit on a single worksheet, comparing a million datetimes with a second set of a million datetimes and removing entries that do not fit both categories is going to be an arduous and time-consuming task.

Arduous and time-consuming tasks are best processed 'in-memory'. Repeatedly returning to the worksheet(s) to compare values is going to bog down processing and should be avoided unless absolutely necessary.

This seems like it should be an SQL question where two different sets of CSVs are loaded into two temporary but consolidated database tables and indexed on their respective datetimes. An [INNER JOIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976856.aspx) could then be performed to build a third table of matching records. Easy-peasy.

But this is an <kbd>excel</kbd> / <kbd>vba</kbd> question and should be answered in kind.

A VBA [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242687.aspx) object is like an in-memory database table and comes with a unique primary 'index' called the [key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ex01tte.aspx). It also has a single additional 'field' of the variant type which can receive any style of value or values that a variant can.  Loading two dictionaries with the respective values (one for temperatures and another for the pressures) using the datetimes as the keys would seem to be the most efficient method of combining the two.

**[Sample data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Temperature_Pressure_CSVs.xlsb)**

I started with several CSVs similar to the following.

[image: Temperature_Pressure_CSVs_sample3]      [image: Temperature_Pressure_CSVs_sample4]
                        <sup>Temperaturen-25.csv</sup>                                                        <sup>SPS-25.csv</sup>

Three temperature CSVs and three pressure CSVs totalled ~300K records (~150K each) with periods of intentionally missing datetimes from each.

**[Module2 (Code)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Temperature_Pressure_CSVs.xlsb)**

```
Option Explicit

'public constant dictating the maximum number of entries per worksheet (never set higher than Rows.Count-3)
Public Const iMAXROWS As Long = 50000

Sub main()
    Dim fp As String, fn As String, tmp As Variant
    Dim dt As Variant, tdic As Object, pdic As Object
    Dim tpwb As Workbook, a As Long, d As Long, w As Long

    'apptggl btggl:=false   'uncomment this when you have finished debugging

    'create 2 dictionary objects to receive ALL of the data
    Set tdic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set pdic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    tdic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare
    pdic.CompareMode = vbBinaryCompare

    'load the dictionaries using the overwrite method
    fp = Environ("TMP") & Chr(92) & "TempPress"
    fn = Dir(fp & Chr(92) & "*.csv", vbNormal)
    Do While CBool(Len(fn))
        Select Case True
            Case LCase(fn) Like "*temperaturen*"
                'debug.Print "found " & fn
                loadTPDictionary CStr(fp & Chr(92) & fn), tdic, 3
            Case LCase(fn) Like "*sps*"
                'debug.Print "found " & fn
                loadTPDictionary CStr(fp & Chr(92) & fn), pdic, 2
            Case Else
                'do nothing; not temperature or pressure
        End Select
        'debug.Print tdic.Count & ":" & pdic.Count
        fn = Dir
    Loop

    'debug.Print tdic.Count
    'debug.Print pdic.Count

    'At this point you have two dictionary object; one for temps and one for pressures
    'They have a unique indexed key on their datetime values
    'Time to merge the two

    'First load all matching pressures into the temperatures
    For Each dt In tdic
        If pdic.Exists(dt) Then
            tdic.Item(dt) = Array(tdic.Item(dt)(0), tdic.Item(dt)(1), tdic.Item(dt)(2), _
                                  pdic.Item(dt)(1), pdic.Item(dt)(0))
        End If
    Next dt

    'Second, get rid of temps that had no matching pressure
    For Each dt In tdic
        If UBound(tdic.Item(dt)) < 4 Then
            tdic.Remove dt
        End If
    Next dt

    'debug.Print tdic.Count
    'debug.Print pdic.Count

    'At this point the temp dictionary object contains a merged set of matching temps and pressures
    'Time to put the values into one or more worksheets

    'create a new target workbook and set up the first target worksheet
    Set tpwb = Workbooks.Add
    With tpwb
        For w = 1 To Int(tdic.Count / iMAXROWS) + 1
            a = 1: d = 1
            'first load an array with the dictionary's values
            ReDim tmp(1 To iMAXROWS, 1 To 5)
            For Each dt In tdic
                If d > (w * iMAXROWS) Then
                    Exit For
                ElseIf d > ((w - 1) * iMAXROWS) Then
                    tmp(a, 1) = tdic.Item(dt)(0)
                    tmp(a, 2) = tdic.Item(dt)(1)
                    tmp(a, 3) = tdic.Item(dt)(2)
                    tmp(a, 4) = tdic.Item(dt)(3)
                    tmp(a, 5) = tdic.Item(dt)(4)
                    a = a + 1
                End If
                d = d + 1
            Next dt

            On Error GoTo bm_Need_Worksheet
            With .Worksheets(w + 1) '<~~ ignore the original blank worksheet from the new workbook
                'dump the values back into the worksheet
                .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(tmp, 1), UBound(tmp, 2)) = tmp
                'format the datetimes
                .Range("A2:A" & UBound(tmp, 1) + 1 & ",E2:E" & UBound(tmp, 1) + 1).NumberFormat = _
                    "[Color10]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
                .Columns("A:E").AutoFit
            End With
            'clear the variant array
            Erase tmp
        Next w
        'get rid of the original unprepped worksheet created with the new workbook
        .Worksheets(1).Delete
        'save as a binary workbook due to size considerations
        .SaveAs Filename:=fp & Chr(92) & Format(Date, "\T\P\_yyyymmdd\_") & CLng(Timer), _
                       FileFormat:=xlExcel12, AddToMru:=True
        'close savechanges:=false   'uncomment this after debugging
    End With

    'we got safely here; skip over worksheet creation
    GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

bm_Need_Worksheet:
    On Error GoTo 0
    With tpwb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        On Error GoTo bm_Need_Worksheet
        .Range("A1:E1") = Array("Date and Time", "Temperature 1", "Temperature 2", _
                                "Pressure", "Date and Time (p)")
        .Name = "Temperaturen & Pressure " & w
        With .Parent.Windows(1)
            .SplitColumn = 0: .SplitRow = 1
            .FreezePanes = True
            .Zoom = 75
        End With
    End With
    Resume

bm_Safe_Exit:
    'discard the dictionary objects
    tdic.RemoveAll: Set tdic = Nothing
    pdic.RemoveAll: Set pdic = Nothing
    'restore the application environment
    appTGGL

End Sub

Sub loadTPDictionary(fpn As String, ByRef dict As Object, flds As Long)
    Dim f As Long, v As Long, vVALs As Variant, wb As Workbook
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=fpn, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                            ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
                            Comma:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, _
                            FieldInfo:=IIf(flds = 3, Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), _
                                                     Array(Array(1, 3), Array(2, 1)))
    With ActiveWorkbook
        With Worksheets(1)
            'Debug.Print .Cells(1, 1).Value
            vVALs = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, flds).End(xlUp)).Value2
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    If flds = 3 Then
        For v = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
            'fastest load method but overwrites duplicate datetime values with the last temp1, temp2
            dict.Item(vVALs(v, 1)) = Array(vVALs(v, 1), vVALs(v, 2), vVALs(v, 3))
        Next v
    Else
        For v = LBound(vVALs, 1) To UBound(vVALs, 1)
            'fastest load method but overwrites duplicate datetime values with the last pressure
            dict.Item(vVALs(v, 1)) = Array(vVALs(v, 1), vVALs(v, 2))
        Next v
    End If

    Erase vVALs

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .AutoRecover.Enabled = bTGGL   'no interruptions with an auto-save
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

Refer to the in-code comments to follow the program flow. I seriously advise you to start with a smaller sample data set and work through the code using <kbd>F8</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. Set some [watches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251700.aspx) on the vars. I've left many `Debug.Print` statements in that can be uncommented and their information observed through the VBE's [Immediate window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278736.aspx).

btw, my default workbooks are created with a single worksheet, not three like the default. You might want to adjust the code to remove everything but a single blank [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) immediately after the creation of a new target [Workbook Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835568.aspx) if you still open a new workbook with three blank worksheets. New worksheets are created to receive the data and are formatted on creation appropriately.

**[Results](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/TP_20160501_65489.xlsb)**

While the results were produced quickly enough, I thought ~150K records (~135K after processing) were sufficient for testing. These results were split into multiple worksheets because of the iMAXROWS constant I set at 50K per worksheet.

[image: Temperature_Pressure_CSVs_results]
                        <sup>TP_20160501_65489.xlsb</sup>

> <sup>150K+150K processed into ~140K consolidated records in ~29 seconds.</sup>

You might also wish to seriously consider moving to a database solution.

---

<sub>See **[Highlight Duplicates and Filter by color alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137329/excel-highlight-duplicates-and-filter-by-color-alternative/35151456#35151456)** for pointers on dealing with large worksheets.</sub>

Comment: I'm willing to entertain questions on the methods used here but please demonstrate that you have tried to answer your question through research first.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will apply this code and find if there are any problems. if i could not solve them by myself, i will let you know.